# What permissions should be reviewed for custom tab with an iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a custom tab for a Facebook Page that will simply have an iframe. It seems like I have to put this through Facebooks review process, but I'm not sure what permissions I should enter it for.

I've been using this guide (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs/) to get the tab up and running. I have the info filled out for the content I want to pull in, I set the App live, but when I try and view the app, I get the message "Misconfigured App Sorry, MY_APP hasn't been approved for display in App Center."

Some more research makes it seem like it might have to be approved by Facebook to set live, but I'm not seeing anything in the Permissions and Features requests that correspond with what my app does (the actual content being pulled in is a simple text field that takes a zip code as an entry).

Comment: Custom tabs for groups does not exists. You are linking to custom tabs for pages.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This is for a Page, question has been revised.

Comment: Don’t know about any restrictions on page tab apps, other than the 2k likes requirement. Can’t find anything about this requiring app center approval in the docs either. Just checked an old app that has never been reviewed for anything, and that still shows up fine on a page where it was installed ages ago.